# Passing Json from Controller to View

Tags: json

I have a database of movies, and I am looking to create a Json, and then access that json in my view. I have successfully created the json within the controller using the following code:

```
   var movies = from m in db.Movies
                     select m;

   string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movies);
```

This creates a json, which I have passed to the Console via writeline, and it generates the following JSON:

```
[{"ID":1,"Title":"When Harry Met Sally","ReleaseDate":"1989-01-11T00:00:00","Genre":"Romantic Comedy","Price":7.99,"Rating":"PG","Review":79.90},
{"ID":2,"Title":"Ghostbusters ","ReleaseDate":"1984-03-13T00:00:00","Genre":"Comedy","Price":8.99,"Rating":"PG","Review":94.90},    
{"ID":3,"Title":"Ghostbusters 2","ReleaseDate":"1986-02-23T00:00:00","Genre":"Comedy","Price":9.99,"Rating":"15","Review":89.90},
{"ID":4,"Title":"Rio Bravo","ReleaseDate":"1959-04-15T00:00:00","Genre":"Western","Price":3.99,"Rating":"U","Review":91.90},
{"ID":5,"Title":"The Hangover","ReleaseDate":"2008-01-01T00:00:00","Genre":"Comedy","Price":9.99,"Rating":"18","Review":83.80}, 
{"ID":6,"Title":"Test","ReleaseDate":"2013-06-01T00:00:00","Genre":"Action","Price":10.00,"Rating":"18","Review":89.00}]
```

I then want to access that json in my view, and print it to my view. I have tried the following Ajax code, but I can't seem to get the json data to display.

```
<button id="test">Test</button>
<div class="inner"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').on('click', function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Movies")',
        dataType: 'json',
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(serverdata) {
        jsonData = serverdata;
        $.each(jsonData, function(i, item) {
           $(".inner").append("<p>" + jsonData + "</p>");
        });
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $(".inner").append("<p>" + jsonData + "</p>"); Shouldn't jsonData be item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we are talking about ASP.NET MVC then you can do this:

action code:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Index(int? PageId)
{
    //other your code goes here
    var movies = from m in db.Movies
                 select m;
    return Json(new {result = movies}),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

client code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Movies")',
        dataType: 'json',
        content: "application/json",
        cache : false
    }).done(function (serverdata) {
        if(result.result.length > 0)
        {
            $.each(result.result, function(i, item) {
                $(".inner").append("<p>" +"ID: "+ item.ID +", Title :" + item.Title+ "</p>");
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("No movies in result");
        }
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Internal server error." + "\n" + jqXHR.statusText );
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Just had to change:
return Json(new {result = movies}),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
to
return Json(new {result = movies},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: The client-side code doesn't actually seem to do anything. Only the json is displayed on the page, and the ajax request doesn't change anything. Does anything need to be changed in order to allow the ajax to control the styling, and positioning of the json?

Comment: styling and positioning of json?

Answer (score 0):

try: -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').on('click', function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Movies")',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        context: document.body
        }).done(function(serverdata) {
        var jsonData = serverdata;
        $.each(jsonData, function(i, item) {
         $(".inner").append("<p>" +"ID: "+ item.ID +", Title :" + item.Title+ "</p>");
       });
    });
  });
});
</script>
```